# Django Backend is giving me this Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have tried just about everything from researching. Basically I have my frontend server and a backend server. My fronend server is getting the error from the backend server that is running Django.

This is my settings in my Django app

```
"""
Django settings for appliAI project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'removed because I am not giving that out'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

# asdf.com has is replacing my actual URL

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "localhost",
    "127.0.0.1",
    "asdf.com",
    "*.asdf.com",
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sslserver',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
]
# Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.asdf\.com$",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_DEBUG = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]


APPEND_SLASH=False

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False



ROOT_URLCONF = 'appliAI.urls_ssl'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appliAI.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SSL_CERTIFICATE_PATH = 'removed for security reassons'
SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = 'removed for security reassons'
```

Here is my front end post

```
axios.post(appliAiUrl + '/getPredictions',
 {
   "username"            : username,
   "company_code"   : company_code,
   "company_id" : company_id
 }
 )
 .then(response => response.data)
 .then(data => {
  processRecommendation(data);
 })
```

I have nginx setup as a reverse proxy server and I have this https://127.0.0.1:8000

I am running out of things to try and I really don't want to give access my server access to all.

I have tried just about basically everything I could think of to try to get this to work. Here is my nginx

```
       location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

I thought by adding CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True would get me to a state where it would work but I was wrong. I also really don't want to do that.

Error message

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'appliai.asdf.com/getPredictions' from origin 'appli.asdf.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. xhr.js:220 POST appliai.asdf.com/getPredictions net::ERR_FAILED

I am running this temporarily until I can fix whatever is going on.

```
python3 manage.py runserver_plus --cert /etc/nginx/ssl/asdf_com/__asdf_com.crt --key /etc/nginx/ssl/asdf.key

2023-12-30 05:31:49.514533: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-12-30 05:31:50.203226: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:31:50.203517: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:31:50.397149: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:31:50.859038: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-12-30 05:31:50.860671: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-30 05:31:52.648624: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Using TensorFlow backend
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on https://127.0.0.1:8000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
Performing system checks...

2023-12-30 05:31:59.266727: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-12-30 05:32:00.448743: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:32:00.449008: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:32:00.709272: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-12-30 05:32:01.259375: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:31] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2023-12-30 05:32:01.270345: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-12-30 05:32:03.106345: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Using TensorFlow backend
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Django version 4.2.7, using settings 'asdf.settings'
Development server is running at https://[127.0.0.1]:8000/
Using the Werkzeug debugger (https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 479-017-511
```

When I try to hit the API nothing appears when I should see something like this

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 72ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 23ms/step
```

Comment: Hay, we need SECRET_KEY to fix this issue. ♦️.

Comment: Why do you need my secret key? I am not just willing to give it out to just anyone.

Comment: To fix your problem. (secretly hack it. Don't tell anybody). My friend.

Comment: I think, it would be a help if you can include full error message.

Comment: Full error message

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://appliai.asdf.com/getPredictions' from origin 'https://appli.asdf.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

xhr.js:220 
POST https://appliai.asdf.com/getPredictions net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: It was just a joke, because you wrote this. (removed because I am not giving that out). But it would actually help us if you can post the error message).

Comment: I just posted above error message. I looked in the network tab and I see 404 errors. I double checked my server and its running perfectly fine and loaded up correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of back and forth trying to get something to work, in the end it was a combination of Nginx and Gunicorn (HTTP vs HTTPS).

When running the Django app via Gunicorn it listens on HTTP by default, not HTTPS. I needed a way to pass in a proxy so that the URL I would use to hit the API would use HTTPS not HTTP.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name     www.test.com;
        root         /var/www;


        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/test_com/__test_com.crt;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}
```

There was one Django setting that I needed to change and that was in the allowed hosts.

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
"localhost",
"127.0.0.1",
"*.test.com",
"asdf.test.com",
]

I had to specify the actual subdomain. Just having *.test.com did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Change according to your domain name.**

In nginx location block add this.

```
location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,X-Amz-Date';
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

can you try this.

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"*.asdf.com",
]
```

Also try this.
If your production uses https.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://asdf.lv', 'https://www.asdf.lv']
```

If your production uses http.

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://asdf.lv', 'http://www.asdf.lv']
```

Django 4.0 and above
For Django 4.0 and above, CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS must include scheme and host, e.g.:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://front.asdf.net']
```

Django 3.2 and lower
For Django 3.2 and lower, CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS must contain only the hostname, without a scheme:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['front.asdf.net']
```

Comment: I changed it to the following:

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    #r"^https://\w+\.asdf\.com$",
    #r"^https://\w+\.asdf\.com$",
    r"*.asdf.com",
]

I am still getting the same error. I should note and it works fine in my development env on my local machine. Its when I deploy it is when it has the issues on my ubuntu server.

Comment: Ok.. That is good information.

Comment: CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://*.asdf.com'] didn't work I also tried https://www.asdf.com and a different subdomain. I also added some additional items to the main post

Comment: Was it the nginx block?

Comment: Set nginx config as in the top of updated answer.

Comment: Location block.

Comment: Just did that and restarted it and I appear to have the same issue.

location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

Comment: Add it in the frist line.

Comment: Done, and same issue

location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

Comment: I added some additional logging to my main post. I don't know if that will help anything or not.